# Getting the name of the row with highest count

Tags: python, pandas

Can anyone help me in getting the name of the `CurrencySymbol` which have the highest count.

```
filt = df['Country'] == 'India'
df.loc[filt]['CurrencySymbol'].value_counts()
```

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| INR | 4918 |
| USD | 133 |
| AED | 16 |
| AUD | 11 |
| EUR | 8 |
| AMD | 7 |
| AFN | 5 |
| CAD | 2 |
| RON | 2 |
| AWG | 2 |
| JPY | 2 |
| ARS | 2 |
| AOA | 2 |

when I tried this:

```
df.loc[filt]['CurrencySymbol'].value_counts().max()
```

It returns me `4918` But I want to return `INR`.

Comment: Because it's already ordered just query the first element of the index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your value count is already ordered, just query the first element of the index of the value count.

```
pd.Series.value_counts().index[0]
```

Eg, for this trivial example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'str': 'free peoples of middle earth'}])
df['str'].value_counts().index[0]
>>> 'free peoples of middle earth'
```